# How to mask password in teradata connector for hadoop(tdch)

Tags: hadoop, teradata, oozie

I prepared a oozie workflow to import data from teradata to hive using teradata connector for hadoop(tdch).

My oozie workflow has username and password to connect to Teradata.

I don't want my password to be visible in oozie config file/ logs. so I wanted to mask my password, for this I have written my password into a file in hdfs and tried giving the path of the file as a value to 
`-password` argument of tdch.

However, **tdch** is not accepting file path. In **sqoop** it is supported using `--password-file` option. But this option is not available in tdch. 
Can any one please help me on how to pass file path as an argument to `-password` option of tdch?

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what about saving password in bash file (`PWD=password`), executing bash file inside `tdch` script file and read password from variable? `--password $PWD`?

Comment: option 2: define password as `export td_password=$(cat /path/to/file/.td_password)` in `bin/oozie-env.sh` file -and use this varibale in ozzie workflow - https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/AG_Install.html#AdvancedCustom_Environment_Settings

Comment: @BigDataLearner : Thanks for the reply. We can also use tdwallet for password masking. I have tried it and its working fine with cli , but if I use tdwallet in oozie configuration file it is giving the below exception.                      com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.                                                                                              Please let me know if you have any idea on this issue. Thanks